# In Mozilla Firebox PIV Certificate is not picking

Tags: firefox, smartcard, mozilla, okta

OKTA PIV card authentication is not working in Mozilla Firefox. It is not picking up the certificate pop up for validating the PIV card.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not a programming question

Comment: Please check if [this](https://web.signer.digital/Home) is what your are looking for... Requires Browser Extension to be installed.